# MEAN (SPA) simple Authorization

Tags: angular, typescript, express, mean-stack, single-page-application

I have a build a application but now I am trying to adept it to a SPA application. And I am stuck on the Authorization.

I can register new users, log them in and retrieving its token. But I dont know what goes wrong when I send the token en try to validate it in my middleware.
**I think I am doing something wrong inside step 3** (because step 1-2 are working) but for completeness i added all steps and my code involved with those steps.

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

1> Register a new account (store account in DB)

backend:

```
router.post("/register", function(req, res){
CreateUser(req.body.username, req.body.password, 0, function(err, nwUser){
    if(err){
        console.log('error: ');
        return res.redirect("register"); //TODO: show the error message in 'err'
    }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
            console.log('success, gonne try to make token:');
            //secret key,TODO: set in variable (or better environment)
            const token = jwt.sign(nwUser.toJSON(), "SECRETCODE");
            const result = res.json({nwUser, token});
            return result;
        });
    });
});
```

2> Login to a account (if successfull send a encrypted token to the Client (angular))

backend:

```
router.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error with logging in!');
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        }
        const token = jwt.sign(foundUser.toJSON(), "SECRETCODE");
        const result = res.json({foundUser, token});
        return result;
    });
});
```

3> If a request now requires authorization, the client(Angular) should also send the token with the request and the backend checks if the token is valid (inside the middleware). If so the data is returned.

how I send the data from angular:

```
const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getToken());

console.log('token before sending in data-storage: ' + this.authService.getToken());
this.httpClient.get<Category[]>(environment.backendServer + '/categories/',
  {observe: 'body', responseType: 'json', headers: headers}).pipe(map(
  (categories) => {
    console.log(categories);
    return categories;
  }
)).subscribe(
  (categories: Category[]) => {
    this.categoryService.setCategories(categories);
  }
);
```

middleware I use on backend:

```
middlewareObj.authenticateJWT = function(req, res, next) {
// check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
//token = undefined????

// decode token
if (token) {

    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('SECRETCODE'), function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
        } else {
            // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
            req.decoded = decoded;
            next();
        }
    });

} else {

    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({
        success: false,
        message: 'No token provided.'
    });

}
}
```

So far i managed to do step 1-2, although there are probably areas that could be improved. But I am stuck on step 3...

I dont understand how I can send the token from Angular to the backend.

Comment: anyone? I am really stuck on this one :(

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the header you're using is matching whichever token you're using.

Instead of looking for

```
req.headers['x-access-token']
```

do

```
req.headers['Authorization']
```

Since that's what you appended to your header. Or if you're sending from the client side, send JSON as

```
{token: this.authService.getToken()}
```